# Can we rename [google-spreadsheets] and [google-spreadsheets-query]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags

We have two tags that include “spreadsheets” within them, and both refer to the Google product: [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) and [google-spreadsheets-query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets-query). In use 3,200 times (approximately) between the two.

We already have in addition: [google-sheets-charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-charts), [google-sheets-addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-addons) and [google-sheets-timestamp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-timestamp).

Removing “preads” from the former two is presumably possible ‘manually’ but at say four edits per hour would take more than one month. As I understand it, a mod could make such changes without bumping all the questions.

Please rename:

[google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) > [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets), and
[google-spreadsheets-query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets-query) > [google-sheets-query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-query)

preferably before the fifth anniversary of the change of name, coming up in a few weeks.

Comment: I have no objections to this.  I'd like some others to weigh in before making such a huge change, though.

Comment: It's good to have latest product name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to do this you need to rename [google-documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-documents) to [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) and [google-presentations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-presentations) to [google-slides](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-slides).

I've come around. The following synonyms should be reversed:

- [google-documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-documents) → [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs)
- [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) → [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)
- [google-presentations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-presentations) → [google-slides](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-slides)

Comment: We certainly don't have to do it.  I don't think it hurts anything to have the latest names for things (we've followed the evolution of Google's various suites, for example), but I honestly don't know if spreadsheets versus sheets is better for SEO.

Comment: I kinda agree with @ale here. There is already a synonym set up for this so editing 3200 questions seems a bit overkill in this instance. Especially when `google-spreadsheets` isn't completely wrong.

Comment: @codingbadger This could be accomplished using a Merge in about 10 seconds, but I agree with your second point.  Let's leave it be.

Comment: @jonsca can tag re-naming be automated?