# Can the name of the [google-team-drive] tag be changed to [google-shared-drive]?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Can we please change the name of the tag [google-team-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-team-drive) to [google-shared-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-shared-drive)?

The name of the feature on G Suite changed from Team Drives to Shared Drives [in June this year](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/04/shared-drives.html). Thus, the tag name [google-team-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-team-drive) is outdated.

I have proposed an edit to the tag wiki.

Comment: Related [Can we rename \[google-spreadsheets\] and \[google-spreadsheets-query\]?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4351/88163)

Comment: Hey @Rubén , I didn't copy ANYTHING when suggesting an edit to the tag info!! I typed that all out of my own head! https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/121140

Comment: Don't take rejection reason literally, there are just few options to choose from. What we are looking for on tag wikis are tag usage guidelines, if those guidelines requires an "obscure" concept it's fine to clarify it directly on the wiki.

Comment: Okay, I'm still a novice at editing tags (the way I put in generic descriptions on economics.stackexchange.com tags hasn't been flagged yet). I'll look into the tag [editing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) and learn how to be a better tag editor.

Comment: Just bear in mind that the purpose of the tag excerpt and wiki is to help users to use the related tag properly and to give a brief guide to write good questions about the subject of the tag. *wiki* means quick not enciclopedia as in *wikipedia* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is done

```
updating post history, 32 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 24 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'google-shared-drive' doesn't exist, renaming to 'google-team-drive'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [google-shared-drive] and [google-team-drive] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym google-team-drive -> google-shared-drive was approved!
```

Comment: Oh wow! This is really cool!